# Configuring Spring Boot with Spring Security makes build fail due to reference to missing dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security

Whenever trying to run `mvn install`, on a Spring Boot project the build fails due to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile
>   (default-compile) on project wave: Fatal error compiling:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for
>   org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource
>   not found -> [Help 1]

Two things solved this issue:

1. **Deleting** the following security configuration

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     @Inject
     private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

     @Inject
     public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth
         .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
     }

     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
         .httpBasic()
           .realmName("Wave")
           .and()
         .authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/wave/service/employees/**").anonymous()
           .antMatchers("/wave/service/**").authenticated()
           .and()
         .sessionManagement()
           .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
     }

   }
   ```

Of coruse, removing the configuration is not an option since it disables security from my application

2. **Adding** the following dependency

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```

However, while adding it made the error disappear, a new similar error (just pointing to another class) appeared:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile
>   (default-compile) on project wave: Fatal error compiling:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for
>   org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAttribute not found -> [Help
>   1]

Fixing this again, I added the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This fixed the issue again, but another error appeared:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile
>   (default-compile) on project wave: Fatal error compiling:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for
>   org.apache.http.Header not found -> [Help 1]

Finally, adding the following dependency fixed all the issues:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, I now have multiple dependencies I am not *using*.

Is there another way to fix this issue?

Comment: What was the final fix? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem by replacing

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
   <version>2.6.4</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

on

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I think this problem in org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor

Answer (score 1):

remove your dependency and add this; this works fine for me after i have removed

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

'

and

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
```

here is my pom.xml file

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>

        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>            
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```